# Can you use SSL WITHOUT Load Balancing - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform charges a ridiculously fee for the load balancer.

I don't really want or need the load balancing features just want my HTTPS.

I'm wondering if I can use my certificates without the "Premium" Tier feature.

The way googles been going lately I wouldn't be surprised if they have to be packaged together for the old $$.

I've had some bad experiences with googles pay as you go payment system so I'll just shut the thing down if there is no alternative I think, I am only using it for some testing.

Thanks in advance, Ben.

Comment: Is $0.60 a day really "ridiculous"? Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#lb

Comment: I mean it's situational. If the web server was mission critical or a source of income the cost would probably be fine. I only need a micro server instance which is the free-tier. The plans gets me into a situation where I am load balancing one instance, hence I am getting no value from it besides the function (GCP managed SSL) that has been packaged with it. So in my case it's a ridiculous fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP's web serving options are here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview.   Static pages, IaaS, container, PaaS.

All of the Google managed certificate, or Google terminated TLS, options I could find were at the load balancer layer.

Naturally you can install your own certificate on an instance. And manage its lifecycle, manage its web server, and add any HA yourself.

Comment: Hey John, In regards to "Naturally you can install your own certificate on an instance. And manage its lifecycle, manage its web server, and add any HA yourself." Are you able to elaborate on this? Perhaps lead me to documentation on how to achieve this, in the best case some tutorial. I suspect the work involved wouldn't justify the effort for me. The last time I managed SSL myself was on a RedHat Server a long time ago and it's a pretty fuzzy memory.

Comment: On VMs, you can do whatever you want on it. Including installing your own certs. But that's not Google managed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for a solution.

Once finding the documentation it's really pretty simple.

In my case I chose to trigger a bitnami installation for my debian VM, below is how you setup an SSL for any of the bitnami installations.

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/infrastructure/lamp/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/